# What is $\sum_{n \geqslant 0} x^{2^n}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, summation

I recently thought about the function

\begin{align*}
F(x) := \sum_{n = 0}^\infty x^{2^n} = x + x^2 + x^4 + x^8 + x^{16} + \cdots, \quad \quad x \in I = (-1,1).
\end{align*}

The series defining $F$ converges uniformly on any $\left[a, b \right] \subset I$, so $F$ is continuous on $I$.

*Is there a closed-form expression for $F(x)$? Is this function somehow related to any "known" functions?*

One vague idea that I got was to try to mimic the derivation of the formula for a geometric series, but doing so involves using the fact that

\begin{align*}
F(x)-F(x^2) = x
\end{align*}

and finding an inverse to the operator $\text{id} - D$ where $D\left[ F \right] (x) = F(x^2)$. (In particular it seems that one would also have to find the right space for $F$ to live in and for $\text{id}$ and $D$ to act on, together with a reasonable topology.)

Comment: Per the MathOverflow answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/178561), the person who studied that lacunary series the most was likely Mahler. A comment also noted that this is sometimes called the Fredholm, despite this not really being justified.

Comment: When I type it into [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%5Bx%5E%282%5En%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2Cinfinity%7D%5D) it exceeds the standard computational time and links me to unsolved mathematics problems among other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no closed-form expression for this sum, in terms of commonly-used special functions.

As a function of the complex variable $z$, the function
$$
F(z) := \sum_{n = 0}^\infty z^{2^n} = z + z^2 + z^4 + z^8 + z^{16} + \cdots, \quad \quad |z|<1
$$
has ["natural boundary"](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalBoundary.html) the whole circle $|z|=1$.  None of the well-known functions [including the elementary functions and the standard special functions] do this.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, just a plot

I got a fine graph with Mathematica, below. It's so fast the convergence, that I needed to add just a few terms for any $x$ in the convergence interval $(-1,1)$.

[image]